# angular2 submit form in typescript

Tags: forms, angular, firefox, typescript, cross-browser

I need to submit a form coming from a payment gateway. Our backend guy asks me to either put the `innerHtml` and send after it rendered. I got it to work on Chrome, but failed on Firefox.

Now I'm trying to fix it on our testing environment, the backend added a JSON return of all the properties I need to replicate the form he was sending me so I can make my own form. But still failing to submit on Firefox.

Does someone have the same experience? Please shed me some light.

Is there any Firefox specific fixes I need to know?

Below is the working code on Chrome and Safari

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef,DoCheck, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { PaymentService } from '../../_services/payment.service';
import { Loader } from '../../_services/loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'bdf-payment-form',
  templateUrl: './payment-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-form.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentFormComponent implements OnInit,DoCheck, AfterViewInit  {

  form : SafeResourceUrl;
  // @ViewChild('paymentFormContainer') container: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('paymentForm') myForm: ElementRef;
  loader;
  constructor(private paymentService:PaymentService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private loaderService: Loader,
    private elRef:ElementRef) { }
  
  ngDoCheck(){
    
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.paymentService.paymentForm);
    this.paymentService.paymentForm ? this.form = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.paymentService.paymentForm) : null
    this.loader = true;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let test;
    if(this.form){ 
      test = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('form')
      console.log(test)
      test.submit();
    }
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `submit()` method to avoid redirection with page refresh.

The http service is used to submit the form data serialized to json from the form. If you have form elements bound to the model then it would be easier to send the model back to the backend.

Comment: I can do this, however. The backend guy said, we need to send it thru html form, because the browser need to go through the url. When the browser visits the url with the fields and values in it. It will go into a OTP (one time password) page, and then a callback will trigger and redirect back to our confirmation page.

is there a better way to do this?

thanks @Roman for the replying.